# index 0 beyond bounds for empty array - Found array but how to fix?

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter

It appears my code runs fine, but if no Twitter Accounts are stored in the device, the app will crash with this error Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
    if (accountStore != nil)
    {
        ACAccountType *accountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];
        if (accountType != nil)
        {
            [accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType options:nil completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
                if (granted)
                {
                    NSArray *twitterAccounts = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];
                    if (twitterAccounts != nil)
                    {

                        ACAccount *currentAccount = [twitterAccounts objectAtIndex:0];
                        if (currentAccount != nil)
                        {
                            NSString *friendListString = @"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friends/list.json?cursor=-1&skip_status=true&include_user_entities=false";


                            SLRequest *request = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET URL:[NSURL URLWithString:friendListString] parameters:nil];
                            if (request != nil)
                            {
                                // 1.1 api requires a user to be logged in.
                                [request setAccount:currentAccount];
                                [request performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
                                    NSInteger responseCode = [urlResponse statusCode];
                                    if (responseCode == 200)
                                    {
                                    // ADD STUFFS HERE

                                            }

                                            [theCollectionView reloadData];

                                        }
                                    } 
                                }];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    NSLog(@"User did not grant access.");
                }

            }];
        } 
    } 
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

I'm not sure why, as I do have the nil check as seen above once it's created? `ACAccount *currentAccount = [twitterAccounts objectAtIndex:0];`  How would I display an `UIAlertView` or something similar if no accounts are found on device, rather then having it crash?

Comment: Simply check `if([twitterAccounts count] > 0)` then do your work otherwise array is empty.

Comment: To checking `if(twitterAccounts!=nil)` doesn't check if there is index available to fetch the object. It just check `twitterAccounts` have been initialized or not. While the error is saying that there is no index 0 available in `twitterAccounts`. So for that `if ([twitterAccounts count] > index){NSLog(@"%@",twitterAccounts[index])}`. Thats it!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `if` to only execute when your array has objects in it, that you can check with `count`

```
if (twitterAccounts.count)
```

Comment: This `if` condition will be `FALSE` if array is empty.

Answer (score 0):

You call `ACAccount *currentAccount = [twitterAccounts objectAtIndex:0];` without first checking to see if there are any accounts.

One option would be to change:

```
if (twitterAccounts != nil)
```

to:

```
if (twitterAccounts.count) {
    // process the account
} else {
    // show alert
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider changing the original code from

```
 if (twitterAccounts != nil)
```

to

```
if (twitterAccounts != nil && twitterAccounts.count)
```